# Facebook API in Grails App

Tags: facebook, grails

I add facebook login posibility in my grails app, but how I can do that, e.x. if user write some comment to the some post in my site, this comment will apear in the facebook wall, or e.x. if I publish new article in the app, it will also publish in facebook fun page automatically.

Comment: did you read Facebook API docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you'll need to register you app into Facebook developers page. Then, they will lend you an app-id. This id is necessary for signing all the request to facebook.

Here you have the site:

> https://developers.facebook.com/

After doing that you can use thoose plugins from your grails application

> http://grails.org/plugins/search?q=social

There, as you can see, you have **Spring Social Facebook** or **Spring Social Core**. The first one it´s like a Stand Alone plugin only for Facebook. You also have another Stand Alone plugin for Twitter or Spring Social Core which is a plugin made by Spring that gives you the opportunity for making interactions with both services (Fb & Tw).

**UPDATE 1**

Here you have the Spring Social Facebook plugin reference guide

> http://static.springsource.org/spring-social-facebook/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/

**UPDATE 2**

More info about the example you commented

> http://static.springsource.org/spring-social-facebook/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/apis.html#facebook-status

**UPDATE 3**

As said on the comments, here´s the way to retrieve the contacts from FB.

> http://static.springsource.org/spring-social-facebook/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/apis.html#facebook-friends

```
List<String> friendIds = facebook.friendOperations().getFriendIds();
FacebookProfile firstFriend = facebook.userOperations().getUserProfile(friendIds.get(0));
```

There are lots of ways of doing this, check the link.

**UPDATE 4**

As said on the comments here´s the way of sharing post or links to the users profile.

> http://static.springsource.org/spring-social-facebook/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/apis.html#facebook-status

Post an status update

```
facebook.feedOperations().updateStatus("I'm trying out Spring Social!");
```

Or a link

```
FacebookLink link = new FacebookLink("http://www.springsource.org/spring-social", 
        "Spring Social", 
        "The Spring Social Project", 
        "Spring Social is an extension to Spring to enable applications to connect with service providers.");
facebook.feedOperations().updateStatus("I'm trying out Spring Social!", link);
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: i know how to use this plugin for log in. but I can not find any tips about how get contact list from FB or post some articles to FB from web app

Comment: @JackDaniel updated my answer, take a look.